# What is the best way to handling XML in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Android device is much slower and have much lower memory compare to PC/server, So what is the best way to handling XML in Android? And I have a set of very complex xml needed to parse. both SAX or DOM will cause too much code. Anybody have good suggestion? I want to make it clean and fast

Answer (score 2):

The Kind of parser you use in your application depends on your requirement. You can try `XMLPullParser` too. You can see the performance of all the three parsers here..

http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/10927_3824221_2/Android-XML-Parser-Performance.htm

There are a few third party XML parsers available too... I was using this parser for one of my previous application and it was fairly fast. It has Xpath implementation in it.

http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/

Comment: 1st link is 404 - moved to http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/Android-XML-Parser-Performance-3824221.htm

Answer (score 1):

Don't care too much about the size of the class files ("the code"), care about the memory consumption of the application. For android, it could be advisable to implement a SAX parser and extract only the information needed to an internal data model.

A DOM builder will create a document for the complete XML document in memory and that might cause performance problems.

Comment: I had to care about the size of code since the xml format may change in feature and I had to worry about maintain cost

Comment: I understand - I thought you wanted to keep the code base small because the application is designd for android mobiles.

Answer (score 1):

[XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) looks like best option available.
Check [Quick Introduction to XmlPull v1 API](http://xmlpull.org/v1/download/unpacked/doc/quick_intro.html).

Also have a look at [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net). 
As per them from their [home page](http://vtd-xml.sf.net),

- The world's most memory-efficient
  (1.3x~1.5x the size of an XML
  document) random-access XML parser.
- The world's fastest XML parser: On a
  Core2 2.5Ghz Laptop, VTD-XML
  outperforms DOM parsers by 5x~12x,
  delivering 90~120 MB/sec per core
  sustained throughput.
- The world's fastest XPath 1.0
  implementation.
- The world's most efficient XML
  indexer that seamlessly integrates
  with your XML applications.
- The world's only incremental-update
  capable XML parser capable of
  cutting, pasting, splitting and
  assembling XML documents with max
  efficiency.
- The world's only XML parser that
  allows you to use XPath to process
  256 GB XML documents.

Following link also has various options you can use:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is [SAX](http://xmlzoo.net/sax/?xml=01.xml) or [XMLPull](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/package-summary.html). Android provides API for both. The main difference here is:

- In SAX, the parser drives the parsing and does callbacks on your code
- In pull parsing the user code drives the parsing.

Below is an example of XmlPull parsing:

```
  try {
     reader = new InputStreamReader(...from soem input stream);
     XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
     parser.setInput(reader);
     parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT, null, null);

     // get the event type
     int eventType = parser.getEventType();

     // see what type of event it is...
     while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String pName = parser.getName();
        switch(eventType) {
           case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
              if(pName.equals("sometag")) {
                 // get the textcontent
                 String msg = parser.nextText(); 
                 // get attribute value
                 String strErrCode = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "somattr");
              break;
           case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
              if(pName.equals("sometag")) {
                 // do something
              }
              break;
           default:
              break;
        } 

        eventType = parser.next(); // parse next and generate event
     } // while loop
  }catch(Exception e) {
     String msg = e.getMessage();
     Log.e(TAG, "Error while parsing response: " + msg, e);
  }
```

Here is a [quick intro](http://www.xmlpull.org/v1/download/unpacked/doc/quick_intro.html) on how to do pull parsing

Comment: pull parse saved a little of code, but the code base still be big since the structure of the xml is so complex