# Convert XML String to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, string

Seems like a basic question but I can't find this anywhere. Basically I've got a list of XML links like so: (all in one string)

I already have the "string" var which contains all the XML. Just extracting the HTML strings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
<photo>
    <src_small>http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/486603_10151153207000351_1200565882_t.jpg</src_small>
</photo>
<photo>
  <src_small>http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/578919_10150988289678715_1110488833_t.jpg</src_small>
</photo>
```

I want to convert these into a arrayList, so something like URLArray[0] would be the first address as a string.

Can anyone tell me how to do this thanks?

Comment: use an XMLReader to parse the XML, building out your ArrayList during parsing.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625506/what-is-the-best-way-to-handling-xml-in-android has some good XML parser choices for android.

Comment: Way to much code for something that should be a simple task?

Comment: This is one of the best answers for this question

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4828765/1087653

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  InputSource is = new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlString) );
  Document doc = builder.parse( is );

  XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
  XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
  xpath.setNamespaceContext(new PersonalNamespaceContext());
  XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//src_small/text()");

  Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
  List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
      urls.add (nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
      System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
  }
```

Comment: What's the personal namespace? I'm getting the error PersonalNamespaceContext cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: that's the xmlns attribute, remove it and try?

Comment: Ah it wasn't in my library, I downloaded here: http://code.google.com/p/fabulous/source/browse/branches/3.0/3.0.0/src/org/unisa/fab/PersonalNamespaceContext.java?r=8

Works great, thanks so much you've saved me hours.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, there should be some other resources out there that can help you. Maybe your searches just do not use the right keywords.

You basically have 2 choices:

1. Use an XML processing library. SAX, DOM, XPATH, & xmlreader are some keywords you can use to find some.
2. Just ignore the fact that your string is xml and perform normal string operations on it. splits, iterate through it, regular expressions, ect...

Answer (score -2):

Yes for that you have to perform [XML Parsing](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152).

then store that in ArrayList.

ex:

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

aList.add("your string");
```