# How do you create a Java array from XML data

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How could you pull data from an XML file and insert into a Java array or array list?

A sample of the XML file below that I would like to import into an array:

```xml
<dataset>
    <record>
    <id>1</id>
    <full_name>Ernestus Ellins</full_name>
    </record>
    <record>
    <id>2</id>
    <full_name>Tyson Haysey</full_name>
       </record>
```

Comment: May be this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833059/convert-xml-string-to-arraylist

Answer (score 0):

```
 String xml = "<dataset><record>\n" +
            "<id>1</id>\n" +
            "<full_name>Ernestus Ellins</full_name>\n" +
            "</record>\n" +
            "<record>\n" +
            "<id>2</id>\n" +
            "<full_name>Tyson Haysey</full_name>\n" +
            "   </record></dataset>";
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
 InputSource is = new InputSource( new StringReader(xml) );
 Document doc = builder.parse( is );
 XPathFactory factoryPath = XPathFactory.newInstance();
 XPath xpath = factoryPath.newXPath();
 XPathExpression exprIds = xpath.compile("//id/text()");
 XPathExpression exprFullName = xpath.compile("//full_name/text()");

 Object ids = exprIds.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
 Object fullNames = exprFullName.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
 NodeList nodesIds = (NodeList) ids;
 NodeList nodesFullNames = (NodeList) fullNames;

 List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < nodesIds.getLength(); i++) {
     records.add (new Record(Integer.parseInt(nodesIds.item(i).getNodeValue()), nodesFullNames.item(i).getNodeValue()));
 }
 System.out.println(records);
```

Record class in my example:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Record {
    private int id;
    private String fullName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the JAXB framework, which allows you to fill POJOs from XML and viceversa, *i.e.*, create XML from POJOs. These operations are called "unmarshalling" and "marshalling," respectively. You can find a complete description of JAXB [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/607267/19449899) and examples of its application at [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb).

You should also use XJC, which permits you to [automatically generate Java classes from XSD files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463231/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-xsd) (which represent the structure of the XML). If you are not confident with XSD files, you can generate them from your XML (there are a lot of online tools).

Once you have created the Java classes from XSD and unmarshalled the XML file, you can manipulate your XML using standard Java.